# How to create a good delete method to remove one record from table using angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I was trying to create a method to delete an employee by its id, so I created multiple logic and all of them gives me an error in the vs code except this method.
It gives me an error on the console when I click on the delete button.
I don't know how to solve it I need help:

**employee-list.component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { employee } from 'src/app/model/employee.model';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/services/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit{

  employees: employee[] = [];

  employeeName:string='';
  employeeNumber:Number=0;
  city:string=""; 
  postalCode:string="";
  state:string="";
  street:string="";
 
  constructor(private employeeService:EmployeeService,
    private http:HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //add employee array

    this.GetAllEmployees();
  }

  GetAllEmployees():void{
    this.employeeService.GetAllEmployees().subscribe({
      next:(data)=>{
        this.employees=data;
        console.log(this.employees);
      }
    })
  }
  //DELETE METHOD:
  deleteEmployee(employeeId: number): void {
    if (employeeId !== null) {
      this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(employeeId).subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.employees = this.employees.filter((emp) => emp.employeeId !== employeeId);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**employee-list.component.html**

```
 <h2>Emloyee List</h2>
<table class="table-stripad" >
<thead>
<tr>
  <th >Employee Name</th>
  <th >Phone Number</th>
  <th >Street</th>
  <th >City</th>
  <th >State</th>
  <th >Postal Code</th>
  <th>View</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees" class="active-row">
  <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
  <td>{{employee?.employeeNumber}}</td>
  <td>{{employee.address?.city}}</td>
  <td>{{employee.address?.street}}</td>
<td>{{employee.address?.state}}</td>
<td>{{employee.address?.postalCode}}</td>
<td>
  <a [routerLink]="['/employees',employee.employeeId]"> 
     <button (click)="(employee.employeeId)" class="btn"  >Detalis</button></a>
</td>
<td>
  <button *ngIf="employee.employeeId !== null" (click)="deleteEmployee(employee.employeeId!)" class="btn">Delete</button>
</td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

**employee.service.ts**

```
//emp delete

deleteEmployee(employeeId:number | null): Observable<void> {
  const url = `${this.API_URL}/${employeeId}`;
  return this.http.delete<void>(url);}
```

**Error message on the console**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3LOi.png)

**endpoint in intelliJ**

```
   @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Integer id){
        EmployeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your API return status 404, which means the resource does not exist. So the api `http://localhost:8080/api/6` doesn't exist.

acoording to your annotation `@DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")`, your API should be `http://localhost:8080/employees/6` or may be `http://localhost:8080/api/employees/6` if you have another annotation `@RequestMapping("/api")` on the backend controller

Comment: The API like the backend there is a ```@RequestMapping("/api")``` ,and the id 6 exist , I know that the error means it is doesn't exist, but it does. And I don't know why it deosn't working

Comment: The ID 6 exist, however the API don't. You should call `http://localhost:8080/api/employees/6` not `http://localhost:8080/api/6`,  check your variable `API_URL`